# blogger posting using php

Tags: php, blogger

one of my friends gave me this code for blogger posting using php. but it's not working. my server already have cURL

```
<?php session_start();
$email = "blogger_email@gmail.com";
$pass = "password";
$blogID= urlencode("blogger_id"); // like 6304924319904337556

// Do Not Modify Below Code
if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionToken'])) {

$ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?Email=$email&Passwd=$pass&service=blogger&accountType=GOOGLE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$resultArray = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$arr = explode("=",$result);
$token = $arr[3];
$_SESSION['sessionToken'] = $token;
}

$entry = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>

<title type='text'>Title of blog post </title>

<content type='xhtml'>

This is testing contnetto post in blog post.

</content>

</entry>";

$len = strlen($entry);

$headers = array("Content-type: application/atom+xml","Content-Length: {$len}","Authorization: GoogleLogin auth={$_SESSION['sessionToken']}","$entry");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.blogger.com/feeds/$blogID/posts/default");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$ERROR_CODE = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($headers);
var_dump($result);
print_r($ERROR_CODE);
exit;

?>
```

when i run this code. getting result like this

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Content-type: application/atom+xml
>       [1] => Content-Length: 208
>       [2] => Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=
>       [3] =>

```
This is testing contnetto post in blog post.
```

)
bool(false)
Array
(
    [url] => https://www.blogger.com/feeds/7493633362314585130/posts/default
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 417
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 4.001117
    [namelookup_time] => 0.001279
    [connect_time] => 0.007472
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.026912
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.028038
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

```
[redirect_url] =>
```

)

blogger won't posing anything . can you help me to fix this code

and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) As explained *[here](http://charleshays.com/mail2blogger-with-images-php/)* this also can be used for blogger posting using php sent to your email address on your blog that contains your secret key. Here is the code:

```
include('class.phpmailer.php');

$gmail_your_name = "YOUR NAME";
$gmail_username = "YOUR GMAIL USERNAME";
$gmail_password = "YOUR GMAIL PASSWORD";
$gmail_email = "YOUR GMAIL EMAIL ADDRESS";
$blogger_secret_key = "YOUR BLOGGER SECRET KEY";
$blogger_url = "YOUR BLOGGER URL";
$image_location = 'C:/YOUR LOCATION OF IMAGE/IMAGE.JPG';
$email_title = "EMAIL TITLE";
$email_body = "EMAIL BODY"; // HTML OK

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->;SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = $gmail_username;
$mail->Password = $gmail_password;
$fromname = $gmail_your_name;

$To = trim($gmail_username.'.'.$blogger_secret_key.'@blogger.com',"\r\n");

$mail->AddAttachment($image_location);
$mail->From = $gmail_email;
$mail->FromName = $fromname;
$mail->Subject = $email_title;
$mail->Body = $email_body;
$mail->AddAddress($To);
$mail->set('X-Priority', '3'); //Priority 1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low
$mail->Send();
```